# Name a list in Scheme

Tags: scheme, imperative-programming

I'm trying to make an array-like data structure in Scheme, and since I need to refer to it (and alter it!) often, I want to give it a name. But from what I've read on various tutorial sites, it looks like the only way to name the list for later reference is with `define`. That would be fine, except it also looks like once I initialize a list with `define`, it becomes more complicated altering or adding to said list. For example, it seems like I wouldn't be able to do just `(append wordlist (element))`, I'd need some manner of ! bang.

Basically my questions boil down to: Is `define` my only hope of naming a list? And if so, am I stuck jumping through hoops changing its elements? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `define` is *the* way for naming things in Scheme. A normal list in Scheme won't allow you to change its elements, because it's immutable - that's one of the things you'll have to learn to live with when working with a functional data structure. Of course you can add elements to it or remove elements to it, but those operations will produce *new* lists, you can't change the elements in-place.

The other option is to use mutable lists instead of normal lists, but if you're just learning to use Scheme, it's better to stick to the immutable lists first and learn the Scheme way to do things in terms of immutable data.

Comment: AFAIK, scheme lists are not immutable. There are some imperative commands to change their elements.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help. I think I can make things work more easily if I add new elements to the front instead of the back...

Comment: @AmberWolfe that's right! the front of a single-linked list is the easiest place to add elements, and the most efficient one. Use `cons` for adding at the front, and don't forget that it creates a new list, it doesn't modify the original list, and you'd need to store it again

Comment: @Vincent Racket's lists are immutable by default

Comment: What's the best way to remove an element from the middle of the list? If I need to alter an element, I presume I have to remove it, then add a new element with the change.

Comment: @AmberWolfe Create a new list, replacing the element you need to remove with the new element (or with the rest of the list, if you simply want to delete it)

Comment: Is there a way to do that without typing out the list? I'm creating a list of the words in a document as part of a word count program. I need to keep track of all the words used and how many times each one occurs, so I'm altering the list, adding to it, and going into the middle of it constantly.

Comment: Maybe you should state that as a new question, it's different from what you're asking in this question

Comment: @AmberWolfe if this answer was helpful for you, please don't forget to accept it ;) (click the check mark to its left)

Comment: @AmberWolfe You *should* post that as a question because it's a very standard thing to do in lisp/scheme

Answer (score 1):

Yes, define is the way to do "assignment" (really naming) in Scheme. Though, if you're writing some kind of package, you might consider wrapping the whole thing inside of a function and then using let to define something you refer to.

Then, of course, you have to have some sort of abstraction to unwrap the functions inside of your "package."

See SICP 2.5 Building Systems with Generic Operations

http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-18.html#%_sec_2.5

Answer (score 0):

`(append wordlist (element))` is creating a new list. What you might want is to use `set!` to redirect a reference to the new list, or `define` a reference to the new list using the same symbol's name.